# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Tags: python, pip, zeromq

I am going to install ZeroMQ library in my pc using pip package installer. I use https://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pyzmq/basics.html#installation as my reference. After executing follwing command:

```
pip install pyzmq-static
```

I get this error:

```
C:\Users\MyName>pip install pyzmq-static
You are using pip version 7.0.1, however version 7.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Collecting pyzmq-static
  Using cached pyzmq-static-2.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-m8zyvx48\pyzmq-static\
setup.py", line 6, in <module>
        long_description = open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'README.
rst')
    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\MyName\
AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-m8zyvx48\pyzmq-static
```

My python version is 3.5 and I use windows 8.0 OS.

**Update**

I found that my referenced article has used python 2.X and I am using python 3.5.

Comment: Are you using Python 3? Seems `str.decode` exists in Python 2, but not in Python 3.

Comment: @tobias_k, yes I use python35. I will update my post.

Comment: is this module available for python 3 version

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why are you using `pyzmq-static` ? According to [this reference](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyzmq-static) `pyzmq-static` is obsolete, the latest package for it was uploaded on 11-09-2012 , maybe it was not developed for python 3.x .

You should instead try using [pyzmq](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyzmq/) (as even indicated by the pypi page for pyzmq-static) .