# Getting "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'"

Tags: python, json

I am a beginner. I can't get a json file to load as a string/dict in Python 3.

```
import json
data = open("Toys_and_Games_5.json", "r")
file = data.read().decode('utf-8')
reviews = json.loads(file)
```

Error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: You're probably using .decode without any need for it. Try ```file = data.read()```

Comment: On https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46408051/python-json-load-set-encoding-to-utf-8 it works. What's in your json file?

Comment: You open the file in text mode, meaning that you already read *string*s not *bytes* (so no need to *decode* them).

Comment: when I remove the decode, I get the following error... JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 321)

Comment: Check the sintax of your json or parse it here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30936826/attributeerror-str-object-has-no-attribute-decode)

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need to do:

```py
import json
data = json.load(open("Toys_and_Games_5.json"))
```